# Inject provider into mongoose schema

Tags: nestjs

Any ideas how could I use in mongoose schema functions (i.e. default/set/get) some fields that need initialised some service/provider i.e. configService. Pseudo code of more or less what I would want to achieve:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

@Schema()
export class Test {
    @Prop({
        default: () => this.configService.get('defaultField'),
    })
    field: string;
}

export type TestDocument = Test & Document;

export const TestSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Test);
```

I'm stuggling to figure out how to inject configService to my Test class.

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. I found this github project where he is using dependency injection to get the configService in his Schema: https://git.io/JEzI6

However this is not working (as I know) with the createForClass syntax.

In the same project he is using the SchemaFactory for other modules so I think he struggled with the same issue: https://git.io/JEzI2 For default values he is using a simple const object there. 

A working .env solution with createForClass would be quite interesting. Maybe set a bounty for it :)